# Fastest way to transpose time ranges to time matrix

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm trying to transpose time value ranges with a certain value (df1) to a matrix based on the index of second frequency (df2).

Currently i'm iterating through the first dataframe and using the loc function to transpose the value to multiple rows in the second dataframe, but I think that is a slow way to do since iterating is horrible slow.

```py
def create_columns(df):
    x = list(dict.fromkeys(df['X']))
    return x


date_rng = pd.date_range(start=df1.iloc[0]['FROM'], end=df1.iloc[-1]['TO'], freq='s')

cols = create_columns(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = [cols], index = date_rng)


for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    date_rng = pd.date_range(start=row['FROM'], end=row['TO'], freq='s')
    df2.loc[date_rng, row['X']] = row['Y']
```

Base df1:

```
    X   FROM                TO                  Y
0   A   01/01/2019 00:00:00 01/01/2019 00:00:09 1
1   B   01/01/2019 00:00:05 01/01/2019 00:00:14 1
2   A   01/01/2019 00:00:10 01/01/2019 00:00:30 0
3   B   01/01/2019 00:00:15 01/01/2019 00:00:40 0
4   C   01/01/2019 00:00:00 01/01/2019 00:01:00 0
```

Result df2:

```
                    A   B   C
01/01/2019 00:00:00 1   1   0
01/01/2019 00:00:01 1   1   0
01/01/2019 00:00:02 1   1   0
01/01/2019 00:00:03 1   1   0
01/01/2019 00:00:04 1   1   0
01/01/2019 00:00:05 1   1   0
01/01/2019 00:00:06 1   1   0
01/01/2019 00:00:07 1   1   0
01/01/2019 00:00:08 1   1   0
01/01/2019 00:00:09 1   1   0
01/01/2019 00:00:10 1   0   0
01/01/2019 00:00:11 1   0   0
01/01/2019 00:00:12 1   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create seconds ranges of datetime between `FROM` and `TO`, add columns `X, Y` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and last use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1['FROM'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['FROM'])
df1['TO'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['TO'])

df2 = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index,pd.date_range(r.FROM, r.TO, freq='s')) 
                 for r in df1.itertuples()]).reset_index()
df2.columns = ['Date','Val']
df2 = df2.join(df1[['X','Y']], on='Val').pivot('Date','X','Y')
```